# can Eclipse browse imported packages and built-in classes?

Tags: eclipse

Can Eclipse browse imported packages and built-in classes or should I just look at internet-based documentation?

Edit: How do I find out the latest method names, argument signature, related classes?

Edit: The above implies I'm not interested a feature that lets me look at library source code.  I just want to write client code.

Edit: I do not see anything under project/properties/java build path/libraries for the purpose of adding Javadoc HTML files.  It has support for adding .JAR and libraries but the JRE is already installed so I don't think I need another library or a JAR.  I just want to look at hierarchies that are already installed.  Does this mean that this feature is seldom used, and badly implemented, so it is un-obvious?  Do most people just use the internet to browse object hierarchies?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The answer is yes, Eclipse can.  In the Outline pane right click and "open type hierarchy".  For built-ins, just right click in the editing pane and "open type hierarchy".

Answer (score 0):

Eclipse can, but you cannot look at the code if no source is available in the imported jars. Not sure about javadoc (if that is available without source).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it can. Go to project->configure build path. There you can find the libraries used and you can attach the source.

Comment: OK, thanks but I don't need the source.  I just want to see the method names, etc..  Project/properties/build path is how you add them.  I already see the JRE library is there, so how do I browse javax.mail.*?

Comment: You can attach the javadoc, too, same way. Find the javadoc for the javax.mail and attach it.

Comment: Do you mean for every import I will have to find some Javadoc and manually add it to Eclipse?  Where do I find them?

Comment: For example, how do I use the Hierarchy browser to look in javax.mail.*?

Comment: @broiyan You have to find the javadoc for the library (one folder or archive per library). For hierarchy browser I think you have to attach the sources.

Comment: One more thing, I use Maven and Maven can generate the eclipse project with all the sources for the imported libraries attached.